# I wrote this code to take in 5 grades take the average and display a message based on the average, it is acting up

Tags: python

I wrote this code to take in 5 grades take the average and display a message based on the average, here is the code:

```
counter=0
grd=0
while counter<5:
    a=int(input('Please enter a grade.'))
    grd=grd+a
    counter=counter+1
avg=int(grd/5)
if avg>=90&avg<=100:
    print('Your average is', avg, 'Excellent!')
if avg>=80&avg<=89:
    print('Your average is', avg, 'Very Good!')
if avg>=70&avg<=79:
    print('Your average is', avg, 'Good')
if avg>=60&avg<=69:
    print('Your average is', avg, 'Satisfactory')
if avg<=50:`enter code here`
    print('Your average is', avg, 'Go Home
```

The issue I'm having is that for the first 4 if statements they display no matter what the average is.

Comment: Please read a tutorial on python's basic syntax! `&` is a binary operation.

Answer (score 8):

You don't use & in python, unless you are dealing with bitwise operations.
Otherwise, you use `and`

Your are looking for:

```
counter=0
grd=0
while counter<5:
    a=int(input('Please enter a grade.'))
    grd=grd+a
    counter=counter+1
avg=int(grd/5)
if avg>=90 and avg<=100:
    print('Your avarage is', avg, 'Excellent!')
if avg>=80 and avg<=89:
    print('Your avarage is', avg, 'Very Good!')
if avg>=70 and avg<=79:
    print('Your avarage is', avg, 'Good')
if avg>=60 and avg<=69:
    print('Your avarage is', avg, 'Satisfactory')
if avg<=50:
    print('Your avarage is', avg, 'Go Home
```

Comment: `90 <= avg <= 100` is also probably worth noting

Answer (score 0):

it is a range test, so you also can code like this:

```
import bisect as bisect
counter,grd = 0,0

while counter < 5:
    a = float(input('Please enter a grade.'))
    grd += a
    counter += 1
avg = grd/5

breakPoint = [50,60,70,80,90]
comment = [' Go Home','',' Satisfactory',' Good',' Very Good!',' Excellent!']
index = bisect.bisect(breakPoint,avg)
remark = 'Your avarage is {}' + comment[index]
print (remark.format(avg) )
```

Answer (score 0):

as noticed in the previous responses, don't use & instead of and. also to handling non-numeric values and do not let them break your program would be beneficial.

```
counter=0
grd=0
while counter<5:
    a=input('Please enter a grade.')
    try: 
        a = int(a) # check if input is convertible to integer    
        grd=grd+a
        counter=counter+1
    except: #if not, print a message
        print ("enter numeric value ") 
        a = 0 # assign zero
        counter = counter # reset counter increment
avg=int(grd/5)
if avg>=90 and avg<=100:
    print('Your avarage is', avg, 'Excellent!')
elif avg>=80 and avg<=89:
    print('Your avarage is', avg, 'Very Good!')
elif avg>=70 and avg<=79:
    print('Your avarage is', avg, 'Good')
elif avg>=60 and avg<=69:
    print('Your avarage is', avg, 'Satisfactory')
elif avg<=50:
    print('Your avarage is', avg, 'Go Home')
else:
    print ("some other message for further development")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
m1=int(input("Enter 1st Sub marks"))
m2=int(input("Enter 2nd Sub marks"))
m3=int(input("Enter 3rd Sub marks"))
m4=int(input("Enter 4th Sub marks"))
m5=int(input("Enter 5th Sub marks"))

avg=(m1+m2+m3+m4+m5)/5
print (int(avg))

if (avg>=90 and avg<=100):
  print ("Grade A")
elif (avg>=80 and avg<90):
  print ("Grade B")
elif (avg>=70 and avg<80):
  print ("Grade C")  
elif (avg>=60 and avg<70):
  print ("Grade D")  
elif (avg>=50 and avg<60):
  print ("Grade E")  
elif (avg>100):
  print ("Entered Marks are out of range")

else:
  print ("FAIL")
```

Comment: Please don't just post a big code block - explain what you did that helps solve OP's problem as well.